VB.NET: '535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful' error message when trying to send mails using OAuth from an Outlook free account
I'm trying to implement OAuth Authentication in a VB.NET project using MailKit for an Outlook FREE account. Not using Office 365 neither Microsoft Exchange. Just a free and personal Outlook account.
I have an app registered in Azure Portal, and that app have 'User.Read' delegated permission for Microsoft Graph. My default directory also have 'offline_access', 'openid', 'profile' and 'SMTP.Send' delegated permissions for Microsoft Graph.
My code works fine until token generation, but, when I try to authenticate user with access token, the error message on title of this question is raised.
The security defaults on tenant properties is disabled.
I don't know if I can do that authentication without a Office 365 account or some Microsoft paid tool.
I believe that the reason of that message error is some misconfiguration on Azure Portal, or something similar.
Public Async Function SendMailUsingOAuth2(Str_Smtp As String, Str_Port As String, Str_From As String, Str_User As String, Str_To As String, Lboc_Items As ListBox.ObjectCollection, Str_Subject As String, Str_Msg As String) As Task`
        Dim Str_AccessToken As String
        
        Str_AccessToken = Await GenerateAccessToken()

        Await SendMail(Str_AccessToken, Str_Smtp, Str_Port, Str_From, Str_User, Str_To, Lboc_Items, Str_Subject, Str_Msg)
    End Function

    Private Async Function SendMail(Str_AccessToken As String, Str_Smtp As String, Str_Port As String, Str_From As String, Str_User As String, Str_To As String, Lboc_Items As ListBox.ObjectCollection, Str_Subject As String, Str_Msg As String) As Task
        'Create email message
        Try
            Dim email As New MimeMessage()
            Dim oauth2 As SaslMechanismOAuth2

            email.From.Add(New MailboxAddress(Str_User, Str_From))
            email.To.Add(New MailboxAddress("", Str_To))
            email.Subject = Str_Subject

            email.Body = New TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) With {
                .Text = Str_Msg
            }

            'Send email
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
            smtp.Connect(Str_Smtp, Convert.ToInt32(Str_Port), SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
            oauth2 = New SaslMechanismOAuth2(Str_From, Str_AccessToken)

            Await smtp.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2).ConfigureAwait(False)

            smtp.Send(email)
            smtp.Disconnect(True)

            MessageBox.Show("E-mail sent successfully!", "Email", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Email", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Function

Thanks in advance.
What did you try?
Tried different configurations on Azure Portal, different implementations for OAuth2, but everything results on the same message error.
What were you expecting?
E-mail sent successfully from an Outlook free account to any other e-mail address.

GenerateAccessToken can you provide that?

In the link below there's a Windows Forms example project using .NET Framework on my personal GitHub. You can clone it on VS 2019 Community. You will need to inform the tenant and client IDs on AzureADConfig class.
https://github.com/8bitdev256/SendMailUsingOAuthForOutlook
